# The cake maker and his dog

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Every night a man makes a cake and eats it.
Sometimes he makes a half a cake, and sometimes none.
Every few years, the dog comes to eat the cake,
But very few times does he eat all of it.
Then the man comes and chases the dog off to make another.

What am I describing?

Comment: ....so, who or what are we figuring out, exactly? Is it also an `enigmatic-puzzle`? I noticed, though, that (ROT13) gur ynfg fragrapr raqf jvgu n pbzzn...

Comment: This should clear things up a bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it maybe:

> Earth (dog), Sun (man), and the Moon (cake)

Every night a man makes a cake and eats it.

> Every night the Moon rises, visible because it reflects the Sun's light.

Sometimes he makes a half a cake, and sometimes none.

> The Moon is not always full, and there are also moonless nights.

Every few years, the dog comes to eat the cake,

> We have eclipse of the Moon every now and then, when the Earth comes between the Sun and the Moon, and throws the shadow on the Moon.

But very few times does he eat all of it.

> But rarely it is a full eclipse.

Then the man comes and chases the dog off to make another,

> When the eclipse is done, the Sun again lights up the Moon. :)

Comment: Well done! You sure are good at this!

Comment: Thanks, I really enjoyed this puzzle, great job making it! :)

Comment: I was *just* thinking of that, especially the Rot13(rpyvcfr)! Anyway, you got there before I did, so you deserve the tick $\,\color{green}{\checkmark}$ :D (DVL14)